# Switch out of postgres UNIX acount

Tags: postgresql, unix, ubuntu-14.04

Using postgresql at an Ubuntu 14.04 command line.

sudo -i -u postgres puts me at

```
postgres@me-iMac:~$
```

How do I get back to my usual UNIX user, that is, to

```
me@me-iMac:~$
```

as I cannot sudo (don't know or cannot set postgres password for UNIX account)? I can close the terminal window, but do I have to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl+D`, `exit` or `logout` should un-sudo you.

Comment: Didn't realize it was so simple. Thanks.